# High Kind Trait impl conflict

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I have two traits which both have a generic type P;

```rust
trait A<P> {}
trait B<P> {}
```

I have an impl A for all B,

```rust
impl<P, T: B<P>> A<P> for T {}
```

now I have a struct S and I want to impl A

for S

```rust
struct S;
// compiled err because conflict with impl<P, T: B<P>> A<P> for T {}
impl<P> A<P> for S {
}
```

It can't compile because conflict impl.
But I can impl for a specific generic type like P = ()

```rust
// compiled
impl A<()> for S {
}
```

There are two questions:

1. Why can't compile although S did't impl B

```rust
impl<P> A<P> for S {
}
```

2. Why compiled when specific P

```rust
impl A<()> for S {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Imagine that I write a new crate that uses your crate and defines a new type `Foo`. And also imagine that I implement `B<Foo>` for `S` (I'm allowed since I wrote `Foo`). Now there are two implementations of `A<Foo>` for `S`: one using my implementation of `B` and your `impl<P, T: B<P>> A<P> for T {}` and another using your `impl<P> A<P> for S`.
2. When you force `P` to be `()` then it is guaranteed that I won't be able to implement `B<()>` for `S` since I wrote neither `B`, `()` nor `S`. So there can't be a conflicting implementation of `A<()>` and your code compiles.

Comment: I know it now, I think generic parameter 'P' is also part of the trait A and B.Is that right? So that every A<P> is a different trait?

Comment: And I think the new crate  not compiled are which i expected. Because I have  had the impl<P> A<P> for S.And I think only in my crate, It should be ok.